# MTU issue with one site only

Tags: windows, mtu

I am currently troubleshooting an issue where some users on Windows 7 and XP systems cannot access an SSL website on our network. The same site works fine on our servers (Server 2003, completely up-to-date, and a Ubuntu Server box) and all of our OSX machines. Our gateway is a machine running ISA 2003, which provides firewall and NAT services to the network.

So far I have narrowed it down to an MTU issue - when I force a Windows 7 box to an MTU of 1100 (for example) the site works fine, but when I change the MTU back up to 1500, the site refuses to load. When doing a "ping test" with "Don't Fragment" and a specific size specified, the MTU can be determined - but it has also changed several times over the past few hours...

At the networking level, when the site refuses to load the remote server sends a TCP reset directly after (or very close to the end of) the SSL handshake.

Is there a way to force an MTU for a specific IP address? Alternatively, is there any explanation for this behaviour (perhaps a method for verifying automatic path MTU discovery is working)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this site remote? Does it use a site to site VPN tunnel? Many vpn tunnels you have to change the MTU, since the overhead of the tunnel packets.  I have seen similar issues when sites have a GRE or IPSEC tunnel. In fact, one we didn't even know it was there, but apparently, the office used 2 different floors on a building, separated by a dozen others, and the building wouldn't let them run their own network, they had to use the buildings "public" one, so someone in networking setup a tunnel between the two routers.

Comment: Yes, the site is remote. I'm not sure if they are using any sort of VPN tunnel, it may be worth contacting them to find out. Thanks.

Comment: +1. I have seen this exact issue many many times, and it has always been on remote sites running through VPN/Encryption tunnels.

Comment: Late reply, been quite busy. They have PMTU disabled but we've also noticed sometimes the site fails to load even with a VERY low MTU. I'll ask a new question with the new information we have and accept yours (as I feel it is correct for the symptoms I outlined in my question). Cheers!